# [NestJs-Pino]RequestId to be used throughout code

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, nestjs

Im logging requestId in logs using [nestjs-pino](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nestjs-pino) as per below code:-

```
import {
  Module,
  HttpModule
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { APP_FILTER } from '@nestjs/core';
import { LoggerModule } from 'nestjs-pino';

import { CorrelationIdGeneratorService } from './services/helpers/generators/correlation-id-generator.service';


const correlationIdGeneratorFactory = {
  providers: [
    CorrelationIdGeneratorService,
    UniqueIdGeneratorService
  ],
  inject: [CorrelationIdGeneratorService],
  useFactory: async (correlationIdGeneratorService: CorrelationIdGeneratorService) => {
    return {
      pinoHttp: {
        genReqId: (request) => {
          correlationIdGeneratorService.generateCorrelationId(request);
          return correlationIdGeneratorService.getCorrelationId();
        },
        level: config.get('log.LEVEL'),
        useLevelLabels: true,
        base: null,
        timestamp: () => {
          return `, "time":"${new Date().toISOString()}"`;
        },
      },
    };
  }
}

@Module({
  imports: [
    LoggerModule.forRootAsync(correlationIdGeneratorFactory)
  ],
  providers: [
    CorrelationIdGeneratorService
  ],
  exports: [
    CorrelationIdGeneratorService
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Now, the issue is i need to pass the requestId generated above in useFactory() function to be used in other class. But, it seems the scope of request id is limited to LoggerModule (nestjs-pino)

Use case:-  I need to add requestId in metaData of a file uploaded which handled by other class.

Any help, is appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution?